# What is the ID of the back arrow drawable in the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-drawable, back, up-navigation

The following code causes a back arrow to appear in the ActionBar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I'm looking for the resource ID of the arrow drawable, i.e. android.R.drawable.xxx.  The reason I need this ID is so that I can manually set an identical arrow (size & colour) elsewhere in my app.

I tried making my own drawable and using that but the size was different from the one in the ActionBar.

Answer (score 57):

If you have the support library in your project, you can make a back button in any place in your applicaction like this:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>
```

Specifically the resource for the back arrow is `?attr/homeAsUpIndicator`.

Comment: How can I get the same ID programmatically?

Comment: @VadimKotov I've added my answer for how to get the same id programmatically.

Answer (score 17):

If you need to use the default back arrow of Android SDK and also with AndroidX then you can reach it with the following

```
androidx.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material
```

---

Additionally,  if you are planning to use it for a custom toolbar then you can set it like this

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(androidx.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material)
```

And if you need to set click listener

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { doSomething() }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily create a back arrow using **Android asset studio**.

Click on `res` folder and then right click on `drawable -> New -> Vector Asset`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The id of the back button in Toolbar is

> android.R.id.home

You can take action from onOptionsItemSelected Method on Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        //Do your task here.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```