# ID of the back arrow drawable in the ActionBar in programming side

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-resources

I am searching for default drawable of back arrow. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807847/what-is-the-id-of-the-back-arrow-drawable-in-the-actionbar) showed how to get it in xml. But I am searching for using in programming side (java/kotlin).

I want to use this drawable id in code like:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, homeAsUpIndicatorId);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the drawable and pass the drawable id to the function. For example, I create a vector drawable called `arrow_back.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0"
        android:autoMirrored="true">
        <path
            android:pathData="M20,11L7.8,11l5.6,-5.6L12,4l-8,8l8,8l1.4,-1.4L7.8,13L20,13L20,11z"
            android:fillColor="#fff"/>
    </vector>
```

> **Note**: the drawable that `homeAsUpIndicatorId` is referencing has a
>   private modifier, so you can't access it directly. However, the above
>   code was copied from the vector drawable with little modification.

I will pass the id to the `getDrawable()` function like this.

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.arrow_back);
```

**EDIT:**
Do the following to get the drawable from `homeAsUpIndicatorId`:

```
    TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme, new int[] {R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator});
    int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, attributeResourceId);
    a.recycle()
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I need default android drawable.

Comment: This worked fine. I don't really see the reason why you should downvote it. Moreover, the XML code I posted is copied from the default vector drawable.

Comment: You can find the original source for the back button here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/1a05e6e0c759f1bb95f1c698150fa17a986d7619/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml and home as indicator here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/ff6a18ccc12673e67ae2b143de1bb27048824365/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml

Comment: By default i mean not adding my drawable.

Comment: Check the edit I did to my post, if that doesn't work for you.Then you need to explain what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet

```
val a = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme, (R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator))
val attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0)
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, attributeResourceId)
```